# Не удаляется ранее загруженная Java-библотека. (Ошибка: ORA-29537: класс или ресурс не могут быть созданы)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

С помощью утилиты командной строки `loadjava` была загружена JAVA библиотека в БД.

Команда с параметрами:

```
loadjava -jarsasdbobjects -resolve -verbose -thin -user login/pass@host:port:SID "sqljdbc.jar"
```

Теперь я пытаюсь удалить эту библиотеку следующим образом:

```
dropjava -jarsasdbobjects -resolve -verbose -thin -user login/pass@host:port:SID "sqljdbc.jar"
```

На что я получаю ошибку:

```
dropping: class com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator
Error while dropping com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator
    ORA-29537: класс или ресурс не могут быть созданы или удалены напрямую
```

И так для каждого класса в этой библиотеке.

Пробовал удалять с помощью `dbms_java.dropjava()` и через `drop java class`, но ошибка была всё та же.

Нужно сказать, что библиотека, загруженная без параметра `-jarsasdbobjects`, удалялась без проблем.

Как мне правильно удалить библиотеку?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410865

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Полное сообщение об ошибке:

```
$ oerr ora 29537
```

> 29537, 00000, "class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly"
> // *Cause: An attempt was made to create or drop **a Java class** or resource that
> //          **is known to result from compilation of an existing Java source object.**
> // *Action: Act on the class or resource by acting on the source, or change
> //          the source so that it no longer defines the class or resource.

Нельзя создать или удалить Java класс, который является результатом компиляции уже существующего Java объекта с исходным кодом (`object_type='JAVA SOURCE'`).

---

Простейший воиспроизводимый пример:

```
$ echo "public class SomeClass { }" >SomeClass.java
$ javac SomeClass.java
$ jar -cvf SomeClass.jar SomeClass.class
$ connstr="user/pass@dbserver/sevice"

$ loadjava -u $connstr -r -v SomeClass.jar
resolving: class SomeClass
Classes Loaded: 1

$ dropjava -u $connstr -v SomeClass.jar
dropping: class SomeClass
```

Пока всё хорошо, но после:

```
$ sqlplus -l -s $connstr <<+++
create or replace and compile java source named SomeClass as
$(<SomeClass.java)
/
+++
Java created.
```

будет создан объект с исходным кодом, и попытки создать или удалить класс с тем же именем как определено в исходном коде, закончатся безуспешно:

```
$ loadjava -u $connstr -r -v SomeClass.jar
Error while creating class SomeClass
    ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly

$ dropjava -u $connstr -v SomeClass.jar
Error while dropping SomeClass
    ORA-29537: class or resource cannot be created or dropped directly
```

Надо сперва удалить объект с исходным кодом и тогда всё опять будет работать:

```
$ sqlplus -l -s $connstr <<+++
drop java source SomeClass;
+++
Java dropped.

$ loadjava -u $connstr -r -v SomeClass.jar
resolving: class SomeClass
Classes Loaded: 1

$ dropjava -u $connstr -v SomeClass.jar
dropping: class SomeClass
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121424) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>